# How to close window using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i created node.js script which takes query string from URL and store some variables in the database after inserting the data I need to close the window or current tab using node.js

Comment: *"...using node.js."* No, you need to do that using JavaScript on the page that sent the request to your Node.js server. You can't reach out from the server and close the browser window on the client.

Comment: `process.exit()` ? (assuming you're talking about a console window sticking around)

Comment: I think you know in the client side when the result of the insert is successful, when it occurs close the window

Comment: @OvidiuDolha: From the "query string from URL" part, I assume the Node.js part of this is a server process.

Answer (score 6):

As NodeJs is a server side language it won't work on client side. So you can rather use following code to close the window. Using express routing:

```
router.get('/close',(req, res) => {
    res.send("<script>window.close();</script > ")})
```

Here we are send a script to the client side which runs on the browser and closes the window succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML page that is being served to the client by your NodeJS server can be closed by using `window.close()`

You can have this behavior triggered manually by including a button on such HTML page, as well as a function that will execute `window.close` when the button is pressed.

If you would rather like the NodeJS server to dictate when the window is ready to be closed, you have a couple options:

- Use a websocket connection for the NodeJS server to instruct the HTML page on the client to execute `window.close()`
- Have the HTML page periodically check (perhaps with a GET request) the server to see if the page is ready to execute `window.close()`